# Dynamically change input's name in .map inside React JSX

Tags: reactjs

```
{this.props.items.map((item, idx) => (
<input type="text" name="name{idx}" ... />
))}
```

Is there a way to dynamically change input's name like:

```
name="name0"
name="name1"
name="name2"
...
```

I tried `name="name{idx}"; name="name"{idx}; name="name"+{idx}; name="name".{idx}; ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<input type="text" name = {`name${idx}`} ... />
```

`name${id}` : this way is called **template literals**,  check the [mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Or you also write by using `+`:

```
<input type="text" name = {"name" + idx} ... />
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I gonna accept your answer later, cuz getting msg "You can accept an answer in 10 minutes"